# Is it possible use an Extended Cartesian kernel with exact Rational number type for boolean operations?

Tags: cgal

I regularly use CGAL for boolean operations (with co-refinement) with Surface_mesh_3 with an exact predicates, exact constructions (EPECK) kernel. Now I need half space representations which it best constructed using extended cartesian, exact rational kernel (ECERK).

I get significant compiler template errors when attempting to use a boolean functions on `Surface_mesh_3<ECERK>` compared with `Surface_mesh_3<EPECK>`, for example `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::corefine_and_compute_union`

Here is an example of the error when using `Surface_mesh_3<ECERK>`

```
      In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/CGAL/Kernel_23/internal/Filtered_projection_traits_3.h:17:
      /opt/homebrew/include/CGAL/Kernel_23/internal/Projection_traits_base_3.h:344:12: error: no matching function for call to 'compare'
          return compare(base * (p - q), 0);
                 ^~~~~~~
      /opt/homebrew/include/CGAL/Triangulation_2.h:3603:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'CGAL::TriangulationProjectionTraitsCartesianFunctors::Compare_along_axis<CGAL::Projection_traits_base_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>>>::operator()' requested here
        return geom_traits().compare_x_2_object()(construct_point(p),
               ^
      /opt/homebrew/include/CGAL/Triangulation_2.h:3638:10: note: in instantiation of member function 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned long, CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>>, CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>>>>::compare_x' requested here
        return compare_x(p,q)== EQUAL && compare_y(p,q)== EQUAL ;
               ^
      /opt/homebrew/include/CGAL/Triangulation_2.h:3018:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned long, CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>>, CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>>>>::xy_equal' requested here
          if (xy_equal(p,finite_vertex()->face()->vertex(0)->point())){
              ^
      /opt/homebrew/include/CGAL/Triangulation_2.h:431:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned long, CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>>, CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>>>>::exact_locate' requested here
          return exact_locate(p, lt, li, start);
                 ^
      /opt/homebrew/include/CGAL/Triangulation_2.h:453:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'CGAL::Triangulation_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned long, CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>>, CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Nef_polynomial<__gmp_expr<mpq_t, mpq_t>>>, false>>>>::generic_locate' requested here
          return generic_locate(p, lt, li, start, Should_filter_tag());
                 ^
      /opt/homebrew/include/CGAL/Constrained_triangulation_2.h:721:9: note: (skipping 5 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
        loc = locate(a, lt, li, start);
```

Comment: What is your kernel declaration/definition?

Comment: Extended cartesian with exact rational is `typedef CGAL::Extended_cartesian<CGAL::Exact_rational> Kernel_ECER; typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel_ECER::Point_3> Surface_mesh_ECER;
`

compared to `typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel_EPECK;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Kernel_EPECK::Point_3> Surface_mesh_EPECK;
`